# Pandas/ Python - Convert one column into new column every X row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which contains values that I need to split and fit in to other columns:

```
column_ex = [Tony, Male,25, Salesman, Jane, Female, 32, Nurse, Bob, Male, 33, Engineer]
```

I also have a dataframe:

```
column_headers = ['name','gender','age','job']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_headers)
```

I want to take column_ex and take every 4 values to fit into my dataframe. How do I do this? R seems to have

`as.data.frame(split(data, 1:x))`

- Is there a pandas equivalent?

Thank you!

Comment: is that a single row? or a series? also please post your expected output

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use numpy's [split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split the data before reading in to a dataframe.

```
#convert column_headers to numpy array
column_ex = np.array(column_ex)
#split into equal numbers
n = len(column_ex)/4
split_data = np.split(column_ex,n)
#read split data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(split_data, columns = column_headers)
```

Another option is a combination of itertool's [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
from itertools import islice
split = [islice(column_ex,part,part+4)
         for part in 
         range(0,len(column_ex),4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(split,columns = column_headers)
```

Alternatively, u could use toolz [partition](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition) method:

```
from toolz import partition
#split data 
split_data = partition(4,column_ex)
#read split_data into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(split_data, columns = column_headers)
print(df)

    name    gender  age job
0   Tony    Male    25  Salesman
1   Jane    Female  32  Nurse
2   Bob Male    33  Engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick, it will assign each column dynamically but for large columns, it might be slow

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(column_headers)):
    df.loc[:, column_headers[i]] = [column_ex[x] for x in range(count, len(column_ex), 4)]
    count += 1
```

Other solution can be done using numpy and `reshape` method which is more efficient:

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array(column_ex)
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array.reshape((-1, 4)), columns=column_headers)
```